# How to trace resource deadlocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've wrote a timer using std::thread - here is how it looks like:

```
TestbedTimer::TestbedTimer(char type, void* contextObject) : 
  Timer(type, contextObject) {
    this->active = false;
}

TestbedTimer::~TestbedTimer(){
    if (this->active) {
        this->active = false;

        if(this->timer->joinable()){

            try {
                this->timer->join();
            } catch (const std::system_error& e) {
                std::cout << "Caught system_error with code " << e.code()  << 
                              " meaning " << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }

       if(timer != nullptr) {
           delete timer;
       }
    }
}

void TestbedTimer::run(unsigned long timeoutInMicroSeconds){
    this->active = true;
    timer = new std::thread(&TestbedTimer::sleep, this, timeoutInMicroSeconds);
}

void TestbedTimer::sleep(unsigned long timeoutInMicroSeconds){
    unsigned long interval = 500000;

    if(timeoutInMicroSeconds < interval){
        interval = timeoutInMicroSeconds;
    }

    while((timeoutInMicroSeconds > 0) && (active == true)){
        if (active) {
            timeoutInMicroSeconds -= interval;
            /// set the sleep time
            std::chrono::microseconds duration(interval);
            /// set thread to sleep
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
        }
    }

    if (active) {
       this->notifyAllListeners();
    } 
}

void TestbedTimer::interrupt(){
    this->active = false;
}
```

I'm not really happy with that kind of implementation since I let the timer sleep for a short interval and check if the active flag has changed (but I don't know a better solution since you can't interrupt a sleep_for call). However, my program core dumps with the following message:

```
thread is joinable
Caught system_error with code generic:35 meaning Resource deadlock avoided
thread has rejoined main scope
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've looked up this error and as seems that I have a thread which waits for another thread (the reason for the resource deadlock). However, I want to find out where exactly this happens. I'm using a C library (which uses pthreads) in my C++ code which provides among other features an option to run as a daemon and I'm afraid that this interfers with my std::thread code. What's the best way to debug this?

I've tried to use helgrind, but this hasn't helped very much (it doesn't find any error).

TIA

** EDIT: The code above is actually not exemplary code, but I code I've written for a routing daemon. The routing algorithm is a reactive meaning it starts a route discovery only if it has no routes to a desired destination and does not try to build up a routing table for every host in its network. Every time a route discovery is triggered a timer is started. If the timer expires the daemon is notified and the packet is dropped. Basically, it looks like that:

```
void Client::startNewRouteDiscovery(Packet* packet) {
    AddressPtr destination = packet->getDestination();
    ...
    startRouteDiscoveryTimer(packet);
    ...
}

void Client::startRouteDiscoveryTimer(const Packet* packet) {
    RouteDiscoveryInfo* discoveryInfo = new RouteDiscoveryInfo(packet);
    /// create a new timer of a certain type
    Timer* timer = getNewTimer(TimerType::ROUTE_DISCOVERY_TIMER, discoveryInfo);
    /// pass that class as callback object which is notified if the timer expires (class implements a interface for that)
    timer->addTimeoutListener(this);
    /// start the timer
    timer->run(routeDiscoveryTimeoutInMilliSeconds * 1000);

    AddressPtr destination = packet->getDestination();
    runningRouteDiscoveries[destination] = timer;
}
```

If the timer has expired the following method is called.

```
void Client::timerHasExpired(Timer* responsibleTimer) {
    char timerType = responsibleTimer->getType();
    switch (timerType) {
        ...
        case TimerType::ROUTE_DISCOVERY_TIMER:
            handleExpiredRouteDiscoveryTimer(responsibleTimer);
            return;
        ....
        default:
            // if this happens its a bug in our code
            logError("Could not identify expired timer");
            delete responsibleTimer;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps to get a better understanding of what I'm doing. However, I did not to intend to bloat the question with that additional code.

Comment: is this code done for some purpose or just for testing? If you wanted to do something please explain what so ppl can give you better solution to your original problem

Comment: `timeoutInMicroSeconds > 0` and `timeoutInMicroSeconds` is `unsigned`?

Comment: You're right about the unsigned long (I don't mean to be unpolite, but that is not related to the resource deadlock).

Comment: You can safely drop the `this->` bits to access object attributes.  You can also remove the test for `nullptr` on timer in `~TimerTestBed` since the code which gets executed before the test assumes that it's not null.

Comment: Use std::condition for sleep: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for

Comment: In std::thread destructor:
Destroys the thread object. If *this still has an associated running thread (i.e. joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread